# Java generics - method parameter

Tags: java, generics

Is it necessary to parametrize the entire interface for this scenario, even though Bar is only being used in a single method?

```
public interface IFoo<T>{

    void method1(Bar<T> bar);

    //Many other methods that don't use Bar....

}  

public class Foo1 implements IFoo<Yellow>{

    void method1(Bar<Yellow> bar){...};

    //Many other methods that don't use Bar....

}


public class Foo2 implements IFoo<Green>{

    void method1(Bar<Green> bar){...};

    //Many other methods that don't use Bar....

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not necessary from a syntactic standpoint. You can also do this:

```
public interface IFoo {

  <T> void method1(Bar<T> bar);

  /* Many other methods that don't use Bar…  */

}
```

Or this:

```
public interface IFoo {

  void method1(Bar<?> bar);

  /* Many other methods that don't use Bar…  */

}
```

The correct choice depends on the semantics of `IFoo` and what its implementations are likely to do with the `Bar` instances they receive through `method1`.

Answer (score 2):

I would ask the question a bit differently, because the `need` suggests a cost, which is not actual. I don't think it actually matter if it is used on only one, or several methods.

When you make several calls to the instance, **how does the type parameter vary?**:

- if *constant once you instantiated the instance*, you parameterize the entire interface.
- if *it may be different on each call*, you parameterize the method.

That way, the type of parameter actually gives information about the code, improve the meaning and clarity.

---

**Edited**: Example

If sometimes, the type parameter varies from call to call, for the same instance ...
*It has to be a method parameter*.

Comment: It is likely that some implementation of IFoo will keep the parameter type constant, while other implementation it may vary :)

Comment: I don't think there would be any way for some implementations to enforce a particular type parameter while others allow it to change.

Answer (score 0):

You're not extending the interface. Is that deliberate? You can do this:

```
public class Foo2 implements IFoo<Green> {
  void method1(Bar<Green> bar);
}
```

Just doing this:

```
public class Foo<Green> {
  void method1(Bar<Green> bar);
}
```

won't compile.

Comment: sorry, should've been implementing.

Comment: I'm glad you pointed that out. It improved the question a lot, so I believe more people will try to answer it now :-)